# How to set document name when printing in Telerik Report

Tags: telerik

I have designed a Telerik report, when printing the report from report viewer, its taking some unique id on the print queue.

How do I document name when printing in Telerik Report viewer.

I found this link when googling,
http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/m-telerik-reporting-processing-reportprocessor-printreport

but i dont know when it will be called ? where to use this?

Comment: What is you plan with this report? What application will call it?(asp, winform, wpf). You want user to dowload it? To Print int on the screen ? Send to printer? Because this is where the file name is define.

Comment: I'm using in Web forms and the print will go to printer, I want to send with name